# ¿Como puedo determinar si los 3 puntos esta alineados? Java cerrado

Tags: java

Requiero saber si 3 puntos estan alieados mediante un metodo estatico o no estatico, en este codigo:

```
class Punto2D {  
    private float x, y;
    public Punto2D(){}
    public Punto2D(float x, float y) {
        setXY(x, y);
    }
    public void setXY(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }

}
```

En el main nada mas le doy valor a los puntos y se imprimen las coordenadas.

Comment: Buenas Julian. Sin más código no podemos ayudarte. Te recomiendo que leas (cómo preguntar)[https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask], y que investigues un poco de algebra lineal, y en especial vectores. En esta comunidad te podemos ayudar cuando lo hayas intentado y tengas algún fallo concreto en tu código.

Comment: Matemáticas: pendientes iguales p1p2 y p2p3, así que create una función para calcular pendientes.

Comment: Hola julian podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber si **tres puntos están alineados** debe cumplirse lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo si tenemos las coordenadas: **A(1;2)**, **B(4;4)**, **C(-2;0)**, entonces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto en este ejemplo **los tres puntos están alineados**, ya que sus coordenadas son proporcionales entre si.

Por lo tanto tu código podría quedar así:

```
public boolean EstanAlineados(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3) 
{
   float calculo1 = (x2 - x1)/(x3 - x2);
   float calculo2 = (y2 - y1)/(y3 - y2);
   
   return (calculo1 == calculo2);
}
```

Este método recibe **6 parámetros** de tipo **float** que serían las coordenadas de los **3 puntos**, se hacen los cálculos correspondientes, y se retorna **True** o **False**, en dependencia de si los puntos están alineados o no.

Para llamar al **método EstanAlineados** desde el **método main** podemos hacer:

```
float x1 = 1;
float y1 = 2;
float x2 = 4;
float y2 = 4;
float x3 = -2;
float y3 = 0;

if (EstanAlineados(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3))
{
   //Imprimir que los puntos están alineados.  
}
else
{
   //Imprimir que los puntos no están alineados. 
}
```

**Nota:** Revisa bien este código y adáptalo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Como no entendí pq me dieron un voto negativo(hay personas q utilizan el anonimato para sabotear buenas respuestas) a mi respuesta original, pues vuelvo a publicar mi respuesta ya que es correcta y funciona

Comment: Supongo que te lo dieron porque el OP [no intentó nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/263200), o bien pedia [realizar una tarea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320/263200), o bien [no mostró ningún error de su código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877/263200), o bien [no realizó ninguna investigación previa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/263200), y se habran molestado porque le has dado el pescado y dudan que así aprenda a pescar.  Que conste que yo no he sido!  :-) Tu respuesta esta bien y no deberia ser votada negativamente, es la pregunta la mala.

Comment: Amigo, lamento no haberte comentado antes. Funcionó perfectamente muchas gracias por tu colaboración, así pude entender mucho mejor el código y el lenguaje.

Comment: @JulianBarrios si la respuesta te resulto util te agradeceria q la marcaras como aceptada, gracias